# OpenDocument Presentation Viewer

Tags: software-rec, openoffice, presentations, libreoffice

In lines of Powerpoint Viewer from Microsoft is there any free viewer for Open Document Presentation(ODP) files? I prepare my presentations in LibreOffice in Ubuntu and am looking for an option to give it along with a viewer for readers using Windows. MS Office 2007 and earlier versions do not open ODP files. Therefore it must be free and provide a quick install/be portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to save to ppt format, the problem is some aspects of your presentation might be modified.

Other possibility is to bring your presentation in a live linux distribution in a usb stick and use it from there; the problem is the live linux distro might not boot right (you might need to change the bios settings of the machine where you want to boot).

A third possibility is to bring a libreoffice installation file and just install it (takes a short time in fact).

You should also bring your fonts since these are never kept in your presentation but used directly from the system you use.